# how to setup security policy for each Principal in JAAS

Tags: java, authorization, jaas

I'm strugling with a small problem since yesterday

this is my security policy

```
grant Principal task02.excercise01.User "admin" {
   permission java.util.PropertyPermission "*", "read, write";
   permission java.io.FilePermission "<<ALL FILES>>", "read";
};
grant Principal task02.excercise01.User "user" {
};
```

when I log to admin I do not have permission to read properties like `System.getProperty("java.home")` also the funny thing is that when I log to `user` I can read files even that I didn't set the permission for that

any advice ?